# xcode viewDidLoad

Tags: xcode, uibutton, viewdidload

I'm getting my feet wet with objective-C.  And thought I'd play with iphone development.
I have a Page Controller.h and .m

Inside my implementation file I've thrown a UIButton inside the viewDidLoad method.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // content that loads in view
    UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    myButton.frame = CGRectMake(10, 160, 300, 44); 
    [myButton setTitle:@"Press Me!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    myButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];

    // add to a view
    [self.view addSubview:myButton];


}
```

So far it's showing fine.  This makes me ask about the difference between loadView vs viewDidLoad.

Also, I want to run my own function when the button is pressed, but I constantly get an executable error from xcode.

Here's what I've interjected within the code above:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // content that loads in view
    UIButton *myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    myButton.frame = CGRectMake(10, 160, 300, 44); 
    [myButton setTitle:@"Press Me!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    myButton.titleLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14];

    //added this
    [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(runClick) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


    // add to a view
    [self.view addSubview:myButton];


}

-(void)runClick{

    NSLog(@"does this work?");

}
```

Does anything seem out of place to anyone?

Also, In the PageController.h I added:  -(void)runClick;

Here's the Error I catch:

2012-03-17 16:04:30.077 Blah[510:207] -[__NSCFString runClick]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a0b4f0

Comment: what's that executable error?

Comment: this: 2012-03-17 16:04:30.077 Blah[510:207] -[__NSCFString runClick]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a0b4f0

Answer (score 1):

About the difference between loadView and viewDidLoad:

- According to Apple, the controller (not you!) calls this method when it's view is requested and it's nil. So, it will create and load the view.
- You can override loadView to create your own view (if you don't have a nib for that controller)
- If you want to add something to the view created by a view controller with a nib file do it on viewDidLoad, and remove it on viewDidUnload.

About the error, can you provide more information? Are you debugging? What's the line it crashes?

Answer (score 1):

Did you declare `-(void)runClick` in your .h file? (obvious question).

Also, if you want to get access to the control's properties (say if it were a slider, etc.), you need to add the sender bit:

`-(void)runClick (id)sender`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to add a colon after runClick as in:

```
action:@selector(runClick:)
```

Comment: the `:` only needs if `selector` accepts the argument. So in this question case the function `- (void) runClick { }` no needs to call it using `:`.